# Transfer all information and tag from div to a CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

As the title says pretty straight forward.

I just need to know how to transfer all of the content from a div into a CKEditor while not transferring the div itself.

It's version 4.1 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, you could just read the contents and setData it in.

```
var html = jQuery('#YourDivSelector').html();
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(html);
```

Comment: or alternatively `var html = document.getElementById('YourDivID').innerHTML` without jQuery.